# Randomly select item from array and only use if it has not been used before

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, compare, var

I am creating a hangman game and I am selecting a random word from a pre-defined array.

Like so:

```js
// Select random word to guess
function getWord() {
  var a = new Array('one', 'two', 'three', 'four');
  return a[parseInt(Math.random() * a.length)];
}
```

Is what I would like to do is to stop it choosing the same word twice or more.
Currently, when using a small array of words, it sometimes repeats the same word 2 or 3 times in a row.

I am not quite sure how to go about combatting this.

First I thought maybe inserting the word into a new variable and then comparing but not sure that is a great way to do.

Any ideas wuld be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: You could [shuffle the array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array), and retrieve values from 0 to length - 1.

Comment: You could use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the element at the random position with `array splice` and then when your array length is `0`, re-initialize it
something like this:

```
var all_words = [];
function getWord() {
    if (all_words.length === 0) {
        all_words = new Array('one', 'two', 'three', 'four');
    }
    var randIndex = parseInt(Math.random() * all_words.length);
    var chosenWord = all_words.splice(randIndex, 1);
    return chosenWord;
}
```

Here a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7cxLbzt4/).

Comment: `var a = new Array('one', 'two', 'three', 'four'); function getWord() { return a.splice(parseInt(Math.random() * a.length), 1)[0]; }`